# React Native / Redux - create helper function connected to Redux store in separate file

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I'm building an app using React Native & Redux and for a `<ListView>` component I'd like to factorise the way in which `dataBlob`, `sectionIDs` & `rowIDs` are created and contain the function within a separate file.

Within the separate file I'd like to create a function called `formatDataForListView` which is passed an array of IDs, with which the correct parts of the Redux store can be retrieved and the `ListView` arrays are constructed accordingly.

I've tried to contain the function within a React element however because I just want to `return (dataBlob, sectionIDs, rowIDs)`, which aren't React elements, I'm getting the error: `A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

What I've done thus far:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class BookingsListViewObjectsCreator extends Component {
  render() {
    const { bookings } = this.props;

    // function that retrieves bookings from Store and structures data
    // into something suitable for ListViewWithSections
    const formatDataForListView = bookingIDs => {
      const dataBlob = {};
      const sectionIDs = [];
      const rowIDs = [];

      // create array of all the different products for grouping into sections
      console.log('bookingIDs: ', bookingIDs);

      bookingIDs.map((id) => {
        // is product already in sectionIDs array? If not, add to sectionIDs & dataBlob
        if (sectionIDs.indexOf(bookings[id].product_id) < 0) {
          sectionIDs.push(bookings[id].product_id);
          dataBlob[bookings[id].product_id] = bookings[id].title;
        }
        // add booking to rowIDs & dataBlob
        rowIDs.push(bookings[id].id);
        dataBlob[bookings[id].product_id + ':' + bookings[id].id] = bookings[id];
        return id;
      });

      console.log('dataBlob: ', dataBlob);
      console.log('sectionIDs: ', sectionIDs);
      console.log('rowIDs: ', rowIDs);
      return { dataBlob, sectionIDs, rowIDs };
    };

    // create objects required to render ListView and return them
    const { dataBlob, sectionIDs, rowIDs } = formatDataForListView(this.props.bookingIDs);
    return (dataBlob, sectionIDs, rowIDs);
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { bookings: state.bookings };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookingsListViewObjectsCreator);
```

So how do I store this straight JS function in a separate file and call it from a React element to retrieve `(dataBlob, sectionIDs, rowIDs)`?

Comment: Import a function from file and use it, just like you would import any other module.

Comment: Thanks for the response @RishatMuhametshin. I can see how to do as you say but how do I connect the Redux store to that function? Currently it is being connected via `connect(mapStateToProps)(BookingsListViewObjectsCreator)` which is outside of the scope of the function `formatDataForListView()`.

Comment: You already have what you need, keep this function pure, the data immutable and entities separated. Your function only renders stuff, it doesn't update data. Therefore, just import it and use as you do right now. The only difference would be that the function is not instantiated per every component render.

Comment: Right, gotya. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think @oldo.nicho means a structure to looks like this. 
Just export that function from a file and import it into the components that need the functionality

// somefile.js

```
// function that retrieves bookings from Store and structures data
// into something suitable for ListViewWithSections
export default function formatDataForListView = bookingIDs => {
  const dataBlob = {};
  const sectionIDs = [];
  const rowIDs = [];

  // create array of all the different products for grouping into sections
  bookingIDs.forEach((id) => {
    // is product already in sectionIDs array? If not, add to sectionIDs & dataBlob
    if (sectionIDs.indexOf(bookings[id].product_id) < 0) {
      sectionIDs.push(bookings[id].product_id);
      dataBlob[bookings[id].product_id] = bookings[id].title;
    }
    // add booking to rowIDs & dataBlob
    rowIDs.push(bookings[id].id);
    dataBlob[bookings[id].product_id + ':' + bookings[id].id] = bookings[id];
  });
  return { dataBlob, sectionIDs, rowIDs };
};
```

// otherfile.js

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import formatDataForListView from './somefile';

class BookingsListViewObjectsCreator extends Component {
  render() {
    const { bookings } = this.props;

    // create objects required to render ListView and return them
    const { dataBlob, sectionIDs, rowIDs } = formatDataForListView(this.props.bookingIDs);
    return (dataBlob, sectionIDs, rowIDs);
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { bookings: state.bookings };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookingsListViewObjectsCreator);
```